# Frigidaire Freezer and Fridge lights dimming and brightening

Tags: electrical, refrigerator

Our electricity went out the other night, but our whole house generator kicked on. Once the power came back on a few hours later, I noticed that every time I opened our Frigidaire refrigerator OR freezer door (they are a side by side combo), the lights inside went from bright to dim to bright again. I would change the light bulb if it were only one, but it's happening on both units. It has been 3 days and it's still happening. I can't find any troubleshooting info in the owner's manual.

Comment: Do you have a multimeter? If you do, check the voltage in random receptacles around the house. They should all have the same (within a volt or two) reading. If some read high and some read low (e.g., 110/130 or 100/140 etc.) then you may have a lost neutral. It is a long-shot, but important to check because it would have **serious** consequences. If voltage everywhere checks out OK then it sounds like something broke in the refrigerator, possibly due to a startup surge.

Comment: Mine does that sometimes...I tighten the bulbs up a bit and the problem goes away.  I think the temperature changes make the bulbs loosen up.